# Achieving multithreaded-like behavoiur using Node.js

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I know Node.js is single-threaded due to the V8 engine implementation. However, I am trying to implement some kind of race between tasks for simulation purposes and so I don't need to actually run on multiple processors. I just need the tasks to run in some pseudo-parallel manner.

More in detail, Given the following description:

```
function task(id) {
  console.log("a");
  console.log("b");
  console.log("c");
  console.log(id + " is the winner");
}
```

I am trying to achieve the following behavior:

1. Run task n times.
2. Each running task has an id.
3. The first task to complete is the winner.
4. The winner's id should be printed.
5. Fairness: any running task should have an even (or very close to even) chance to win, independently of the execution order.
6. Only one win declaration should be logged.

I tried this naive approach to modify `task()` but the fairness isn't achieved as well as the one declaration problem:

```
async function task(id) {
  console.log("a");
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log("b");
  await sleep(1000);
  console.log("c");
  console.log(id + "is the winner");
}
```

And execute:

```
task(1);
task(2);
task(3);
task(4);
task(5);
task(6);
task(7);
task(8);
task(9);
task(10);
```

How can I achieve this with some changes to `task()` and/or any other auxiliary code?

P.S The code in `task()` is simplified for readability reasons and must be run.

Comment: **I know Node.js is single-threaded due to the V8 engine implementation."* Single thread *per JavaScript environment,* but Node.js has had [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) for some years now. Like web workers, they run in their own isolated environment with easy message-passing between the main thread and the worker.

Comment: "*any running task should have an even chance to win*" - just use `Math.random()` to determine the winner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's really a simulation it's not clear that multiple threading would be required. You could:

- Arbitrarily pick a winner (`Math.random`).
- Algorithmically pick a winner based on the details of your simulation.
- Run each of them keeping track of how long they took, and then pick the fastest.

But if you wanted to run them literally in an overlapping runtime race:

> I know Node.js is single-threaded due to the V8 engine implementation.

A single thread *per JavaScript environment,* but Node.js has had [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) for some years now. Like web workers, they run in their own isolated environment with easy message-passing between the main thread and the worker. They run as simultaneously as the underlying hardware allows.

So you could fire up *n* workers, send them a "start" message, and have them post back their ID when they finish. First ID back is the winner.

I was thinking that synchronizing the start might be a bit tricky, but there's an experimental [`BroadcastChannel`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_class_broadcastchannel_extends_eventtarget) for one-to-many communication, so you could send a message on a broadcast channel from the parent that all the workers listen to.

Just beware that since they're all running at once, they're competing for resources, including potentially CPU, even though they're isolated threads.